# How to merge arrays from multiple arrays in two JSON with JQ

Tags: linux, json, jq

I have two JSON files (`file1.json` and `file2.json`) with the following same structure as defined below with two array lists as shown below.

The first file is (`file1.json`):

```json
{
  "Lists1": [
   {
      "point": "a",
      "coordinates": [
        2289.48096,
        2093.48096
      ]
   }
  ],
  "Lists2": [
   {
      "point": "b",
      "coordinates": [
        2289.48096,
        2093.48096
      ]
   }
 ]
}
```

The second file is (`file2.json`):

```json
{
  "Lists1": [
   {
      "point": "c",
      "coordinates": [
        2289.48096,
        2093.48096
      ]
   }
  ],
  "Lists2": [
   {
      "point": "d",
      "coordinates": [
        2289.48096,
        2093.48096
      ]
   }
 ]
}
```

so my expected output will be:

```json
{
  "Lists1": [
   {
      "point": "a",
      "coordinates": [
        2289.48096,
        2093.48096
      ]
   },
   {
      "point": "c",
      "coordinates": [
        2289.48096,
        2093.48096
      ]
   }
  ]
  "Lists2": [
   {
      "point": "b",
      "coordinates": [
        2289.48096,
        2093.48096
      ]
   },
   {
      "point": "d",
      "coordinates": [
        2289.48096,
        2093.48096
      ]
   }
 ]
}
```

I am trying to merge (combine) these two files using `jq`. I found using the command below, but this only work with one list.

```bsh
jq -n '{ list1: [ inputs.list1 ] | add }' file1.json file2.json
```

Is there a way to modify this function to combine both `list1` and `list2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the top-most keys of all documents are always the same across all documents, extract the keys into a separate variable, then reduce (accumulate) the data over these keys.

```bsh
jq -s '
    (.[0] | keys[]) as $k |
    reduce .[] as $item (null; .[$k] += $item[$k])' file*.json
```

Note the use of `-s` to read all the input into a single array.

This, more or less, iterates over the keys `Lists1` and `Lists2` for each document, accumulating the data in a new structure (`null` from the start).

Assuming that the input JSON documents are well-formed:

```json
{
"Lists1": [{"point":"a","coordinates":[2289.48096,2093.48096]}],
"Lists2": [{"point":"b","coordinates":[2289.48096,2093.48096]}]
}
```

```json
{
"Lists1": [{"point":"c","coordinates":[2289.48096,2093.48096]}],
"Lists2": [{"point":"d","coordinates":[2289.48096,2093.48096]}]
}
```

You will get the following resulting document containing two objects:

```json
{
"Lists1": [{"point":"a","coordinates":[2289.48096,2093.48096]},{"point":"c","coordinates":[2289.48096,2093.48096]}]
}
{
"Lists2": [{"point":"b","coordinates":[2289.48096,2093.48096]},{"point":"d","coordinates":[2289.48096,2093.48096]}]
}
```

Would you want the two keys in the same object:

```bsh
jq -s '
    [ (.[0] | keys[]) as $k |
      reduce .[] as $item (null; .[$k] += $item[$k]) ] | add' file*.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If the keys are **not** always the same across the document this one will do the job:

```bsh
jq --slurp '
    reduce (.[] | to_entries | .[]) as {$key, $value} (
        {};
        .[$k] += $v
    )
    ' file*.json
```

Given these two files:

```
{
    "Lists1": [{"point":"a","coordinates":"..."],
    "Lists2": [{"point":"b","coordinates":"..."}]
}
```

```
{
    "Lists1": [{"point":"c","coordinates":"..."}],
    "Lists2": [{"point":"d","coordinates":"..."}],
    "Lists3": [{"point":"e","coordinates":"..."}]
}
```

the output is:

```json
{
    "Lists1":[{"point":"a","coordinates":"..."},{"point":"c","coordinates":"..."}],
    "Lists2":[{"point":"b","coordinates":"..."},{"point":"d","coordinates":"..."}],
    "Lists3":[{"point":"e","coordinates":"..."}]
}
```